# Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on crypto 2.1.5 and Cruise depends on crypto 3.0.0, flutter_driver from sdk is forbidden

Tags: flutter

when I compile my project in fedora 32, shows this error:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in cruise-open...
Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on crypto 2.1.5 and Cruise depends on crypto 3.0.0, flutter_driver from sdk is forbidden.
So, because Cruise depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because Cruise depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.)
```

this is my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
name: Cruise
description: A RSS article read Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.17.0
  meta: ^1.1.8
  flutter_svg: 0.19.0
  logger: 0.9.4
  scoped_model: ^1.1.0
  shrine_images: ^1.1.2
  flare_dart: 2.3.4
  flare_flutter: ^2.0.2
  vector_math: ^2.0.8
  collection: ^1.14.0
  package_info: ^0.4.0
  fluttertoast: 7.1.6
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.0
  adaptive_breakpoints: ^0.0.2
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  flutter_icons: ^1.0.0
  timeago: 2.0.26
  animations: 1.1.2
  flutter_hooks: ^0.12.0
  share: ^0.6.4+3
  shimmer: 1.1.1
  crypto: 3.0.0
  url_launcher: 5.5.0
  uni_links: 0.4.0
  flutter_html: 1.2.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
  state_notifier: ^0.5.0
  flutter_secure_storage: 3.3.3
  flutter_slidable: "^0.5.5"
  hive: ^1.4.1+1
  pull_to_refresh: 1.6.3
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.5.0
  dio: 3.0.10
  fish_redux: 0.3.4
  hive_flutter: 0.3.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  test:
  path:
  args:
  grinder: ^0.8.0
  pedantic: ^1.9.0
  string_scanner: ^1.0.5

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
```

what should I do to fix it? This is the flutter version info:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open% flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Can you try not setting the version for `crypto` in `pubspec.yaml`? Like this: `crypto:`. This should get rid of the version conflicts.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Andrej it's because flutter_driver depends on crypto: 2.1.5

Comment: I remove the flutter_driver in pubspec.yaml @user3875913

Comment: ahh yes, do you know if there is any way to fork the library?

Comment: sorry answered my own question, it is updated in the repo, i don't know why it is not reflecting...

Comment: Have you checked [this article](https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because the `flutter_driver`'s null-safety migration didn't make it in time.

Even though it's now fixed, it won't be released in stable channel until around early June (or with the next stable channel release).

Meanwhile, we have two solutions:

1. Use the `beta` or `dev` channel to get the fix ASAP.
2. Use `dependency_overrides` in your `pubspec.yaml` to keep using `flutter_driver` with your Flutter 2 (while staying in `stable` channel).

I prefer the second choice. So I edit my `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```
dependencies:
  # my list of deps...

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  test: any
  # my other dev_deps...

# add this section
dependency_overrides:
  convert: ^3.0.0
  crypto: ^3.0.0
# add this section
```

This solution worked for me. I can now install `flutter_driver`.

This is my reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77282

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by changing my sdk constraints in the pubspec.yaml to

```
environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

**and changed from flutters stable channel to master channel**

Answer (score 0):

Add [crypto](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto) to dependencies and run `flutter  pub get`:

```
dependencies:
  crypto: ^3.0.0
```

Comment: The problem is that `flutter_driver` requires `crypto: ^2.1.5` and will fail with `crypto: ^3.0.0` despite crypto 3 being the null-safety release for Flutter 2.

Comment: Good to know. Tnx for note!

Answer (score 0):

Use next approach. But be careful, tests might be break.
Insert next code in your pubspec.yaml after dependencies section

```
dependency_overrides:
  crypto: 3.0.0
```